# convert the strings in the lists in list to integers

Tags: python-3.x

unit_cost=open("/Users/amit/Downloads/NetworkDesign 3/small_example/unit_tran_cost.txt","r")
ucost=unit_cost.read

unitcostlist_of_lists=[]

for line in unit_cost:

```
inner_list = [i for i in line.split()]
unitcostlist_of_lists.append(inner_list)
```

unitcostlist_of_lists

output of this is : [['4,16,8,4'], ['6,6,6,9'], ['12,15,7,8']]

Desired output is : [['4','16','8','4'],['6','6','6','9'],['12','15','7','8']]

the file i am opening looks like:

4,16,8,4

6,6,6,9

12,15,7,8

Comment: Please organize your question, try to write complete sentences. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: your code does not even run - f,e, missing `()` after read. missing print statements etc. Do you want an equally sloppy answer? If not, please provide a  [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that lets us at least verify and replicate your "output".

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to chance `split()` to `split(",")`, i.e.

```
inner_list = [i for i in line.split(",")]
unitcostlist_of_lists.append(inner_list)
```

should do the trick.